# How/where to download openjdk/openjre for windows

Tags: download, java

How do I go about downloading OpenJDK and OpenJRE  for Windows ?

Is there a Server version of Open JRE ?

The reason I'm asking is since googling around didn't get me anywhere. Since more and more companies have started looking at openjdk/openjre, and some of us need to deploy/develop on windows, this is a valid question.

If you think building the open jdk/jre is the only solution for now, pls. say so.

All : It's not a duplicate. Since the original question was asked (and corresponding answers), JDK 8 has been released. The OpenJDK site does not have OpenJDK 8 or OpenJRE 8 binaries. It's quite difficult for a java developer to build one for himself. I'm looking for an "Official" OpenJDK, client OpenJRE, server OpenJRE that I can download and redistribute as per the license.

Comment: I assume you have googled this already (from your rep) so I am not sure what your doubt is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Why aren't there official "OpenJDK" builds for Windows ? I'm looking for OpenJDK version 7 and 8. Also, OpenJRE version 7 and 8. All I got from that earlier "duplicate" question's answers were the unofficial OpenJDK 7 build 31 and below. I don't have anything later, like OpenJDK 8.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no official builds of OpenJDK, sadly. Our official stance is that OpenJDK project does not publish binaries. (Personally, I don't agree with this stance). That said, third parties like Red Hat and Azul provide binaries for OpenJDK 8. No binaries for the "server" build, AFAIK.

Comment: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild ?

Comment: https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Answer (score 3):

> How do I go about downloading OpenJDK and OpenJRE for Windows ?

On the OpenJDK home page it states

> Download and install the open-source JDK 8 for most popular Linux distributions. If you came here looking for Oracle JDK 8 product binaries for Solaris, Linux, Mac OS X, or Windows, which are based largely on the same code, you can download them from java.oracle.com.

You can download and built the OpenJDK yourself, as others have done, however I am not sure this is a good idea for a production instance and it is a pretty complicated product to build and test.

> Is there a Server version of Open JRE ?

Yes, the server JVM runs by default on Linux and 64-bit windows.

> If you think building the open jdk/jre is the only solution for now

There is plenty of other free JDKs including Oracle's and IBM's

If you want support I suggest considering Azul's Zulu.

Comment: The website has no downloads for windows. I guess that's why. They can be downloaded here: https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds#openjdk-unofficial-installers-for-windows-linux-and-mac-os-x

Comment: @f1sh good point, I missed that.  I have have included a quote suggesting it is better to use the Oracle release.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : I didn't give you the downvote.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : OpenJDK has a different license than the oracle jdk. if I am choosing OpenJDK over the Oracle JDK, I should be able to download  the OpenJDK bits and not the Oracle JDK bits. right ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey : It's not very popular, but oracle has a Separate download of Server JRE(new) and Client JRE(old). "The Server JRE includes tools for JVM monitoring and tools commonly required for server applications, but does not include browser integration (the Java plug-in).". you can download it at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Zulu, I saw the response from Zulu's manager from the earlier post. However, what guarantee do I have that the bits are the same as the OpenJDK site ? Also, they're behind the public JDK 8 version -- currently 8u72 vs official release of 8u77. Also, I didn't see a separate JRE vs JDK -- only JDK. So, currently, other offerings don't have equivalent to official offerings.

Comment: "There is plenty of other free JDKs including Oracle's and IBM's" -- except there's a mandate that we're to use the OpenJDK going forward. That's why the question. Thank you.

Comment: @anjanb if there is a mandate to use an open source JVM, perhaps the open source operating system it appears to prefer would be ideal. I wouldn't consider using the OpenJDK on Windows for production unless it was either supported or more widely used. I don't think this is something you would want to support yourself.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Re "you can download them from java.oracle.com", isn't that the Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK?

Comment: @Pacerier correct, which is what I said. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I'd thought that Oracle JDK === OpenJDK now. Such confuse.

Comment: @Pacerier very similar but not the same with different license restrictions and releases.

Comment: If anyone's interested and has a Red hat Developer account they have windows MSI installer version OpenJDK 8u151 [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download/)

Comment: AdoptJDK provides various JDKs https://adoptopenjdk.net/.

Comment: https://sdkman.io/  provides a way to install any JDK (Azul, AdoptJDK, oracle, J9..)